# Rails 3 Actionmailer - How to send only if email exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

I have a Rails 3 app sending emails to multiple (2) recipients.  The first recipient is required, but the second is not required.  I get an error if the second recipient is null.  How do I bypass the secondary email if null without getting an error?

```
  def email_approvers(invoice)
    @subject          = 'Invoice Approval Request'
    @body["invoice"]  = invoice
    @recipients       = invoice.approver_email, invoice.alternate_approver_email
    @from             = "..."
    @sent_on          = Time.now
    @headers          = {}    
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

You should see http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#complete-list-of-action-mailer-methods (2.3.4 Sending Email To Multiple Recipients). You can make an array with the emails (maybe in the class Invoice you can create a method that returns an array of valid emails).

In the mailer:

```
default :from => "..."

def email_approvers(invoice)
    @data  = invoice    
    mail :to => @data.recipients, :subject => 'Invoice Approval Request'
end
```

In the Invoice model:

```
def recipients
    return alternate_approver_email.nil? ? [approver_email] : [approver_email, alternate_approver_email]
end
```

--

For your case (it will set the property to **nil** if there is no value, so the previous code will work):

```
def alternate_approver_email
   self.alternate_approver_email = !self.alternate_approver_username.nil? ? self.alternate_approver_username + "@email.com" : nil
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  Can you help me with a skeleton of that method?  I'm not quite understanding...

Comment: Sorry, Im barely watching the message. I will edit the answer and add the example

Comment: Thanks for that.  When the alternate_approver_email is null, I get the following error:  `NoMethodError (undefined method 'encoding' for ["joeschmo@email.com", "@email.com"]:Array) `

Comment: Oh, I know why that's happening.  I have another method in the invoice model that appends the email.com to the alternate_approver's username:  `def alternate_approver_email
    self.alternate_approver_email = self.alternate_approver_username + "@email.com"
  end `  So, how do I fix that method to ignore if null?

Comment: You can always create the method recipients, and, in that method, assign the result of the method alternate_approver_email to a variable, and check if the variable != "" (also, in this case you will need to modify the method alternate_approver_email, so it return a empty string if  self.alternate_approver_email is empty or null). I will add the code for your case.